# Swift: Cant create button action on TableViewController (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift

Im not able to create an action from a button inside my table view controller 
[TableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTJf1.png)

When I drag the button (to create a method/action) to the ViewController.swift, it wont let me create an action. While the table is being shown, when the user presses the button, the app should take a value the user previously entered on the previous page and I cant do that without an action. Am I doing something wrong?

I was only able to find an Objective C answer, but I need one for Swift.

Comment: could you please share your code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are dragging it to the right view controller ? At the storyboard, try to change the tableViewController class (at the inspector) to be the same one as the view you are trying to add this action

Answer (score 0):

you can create programmatically..
just create button , set frame and add this line

```
cell.addSubview(newButton)
```